# read a PCAP file with Lua script

Tags: time, lua, pcap

I have a Lua script to read a PCAP file. For a packet, I can get its time with the expression

```
os.date("%Y/%m/%d %X", last_pinfo.abs_ts)
```

The result is like "2012/05/24 11:32:50", but I want the result like "May 24, 2012 11:32:50.476690000". Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua's `os.date` follows the same format as C's [strftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) function.

However, time in standard Lua only goes accurate up to seconds. You'll have to add the decimal part of the seconds from another source, eg LuaSocket's [`socket.gettime()`](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/socket.html#gettime):

```
require 'socket'
time=socket.gettime()
print(os.date("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")..select(2,math.modf(time),time)
```

Comment: You can get sub-second precision time from socket.gettime() in LuaSocket.

Comment: Thanks, adjusted, Adjusted my answer to include your suggestion!

Comment: Thank you. I don't know there is a module socket in lua. That really helps. But i have another question, when i use socket.gettime(), how can i know which packet i am reading? In my code, i have "pinfo" to indicate the packet that i need. But with "socket", i am not sure.

Comment: the one with socket.gettime() is just to get the current time on the machine. You can format any thing in the time variable, wherever you get it. It just needs to be in seconds since epoch. Judging from your example code, you'd use `last_pinfo.abs_ts`

Comment: Ok, i get it. Thank you so much.